# React -unbale to load the contents after fetch api call in child component

Tags: reactjs

I have mainly 3 components-
Contact Component - it will load ,since the fetch api is written in ComponentDidMount and we can see the data-its showing the list of users

And when you click on particular user-it have id as param and will call another api in handleClick and will get the response successfully and updated the state. Ideally when state updated,contact Component render need to render again,and we have the data in state and it will show the child component,but its not showing.

**My understanding is that whenever state changes component will re render again ,at that time,my condition gets satisfies and will show the child component.
Please correct me if am wrong**

here is the link to editor with code

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-microservice-4jem7?fontsize=14

````
    ```Step1-Click on Contact link```

    ```Step2-ComponentDidMount works and will load content```

    ```Step3-try to click any edit button of any user-HandleClick will work and will fecth data and update state,but its not showing the child component,thats is supposed to render when data is there```
````

Comment: Please add the code that you tried. and the components you have.

Comment: @its4zahoor can you check this link -https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-microservice-4jem7?fontsize=14

it have all components inside src folder

Comment: I saw, it works fine, you have confused your data object with fetchUser object.

Comment: see this, https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-voice-0n9nn?fontsize=14

Comment: @its4zahoor -No ,its not that expected way of working.
See i have contact component and it have 2 child component . 1 ->GetDetailsOfContact and 2->GetDetailsContentSection

The **GetDetailsOfContact ** take the componentDidmount data and takes the data and it do have one handleclick which actually call another api to fetch particular user details.and update state fetchUserData. once this data is there ,it will call another child component **GetDetailsContentSection** and will show each user details

Comment: Also your `GetDetailsOfContact` component code is missing. so I don't know what's happening in there.

Comment: Can you please check this url -it do have all components
https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-microservice-4jem7?fontsize=14

Comment: @its4zahoor At first contact click-its loading all user wit Names. Along with names it do have an edit option when you click on that ,it invokes handleClick(id) function and it call api to get the data for the same id and if data there ,it update state **fetchUser**,hence it re renders contact component and inside that we are checking if this.state.fetchUser.length>0 then we are invoking another component named **GetDetailsContentSection** to show that particular user company details.. Hope this helps

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200631/discussion-between-its4zahoor-and-midhun-k).

Comment: sure..am in chat room @its4zahoor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical error

1. The `fetchUser` is an object so the conditional rendering `fetchUser.length > 0 && <Component />` will not do any component render as `(object.length = undefined) > 0 = false`.
2. Due to the above your child component will not have an array to `map()` so just show the object there.

The Fixed Code can be seen here on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-liskov-d34cs?fontsize=14).